# How to use subfig package in articleclass: spieman?

Tags: subfig

I am using class article `spieman` to prepare my document. However, I am not able  to use `subfig` package. Can anybody guide me about splitting a figure window into the multiple figures in articleclass `spieman`?

Sample code is pasted below and screenshot of the error message is attached herewith. Please help.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{spieman}  % 12pt font required by SPIE;

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{tocloft}

\title{Sample Paper}

\author[a]{Samadhan }
\renewcommand{\cftdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\cftpagenumbersoff{figure}
\cftpagenumbersoff{table} 
\begin{document} 
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\keywords{a,b,c}

\begin{spacing}{1}   % use double spacing for rest of manuscript
\section{Introduction}
\label{sect:intro}  % \label{} allows reference to this section
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{center}
\graphicspath{{F:/Figures/spie_figures}}
\subfloat[Original Multispectral ]{
\includegraphics[width=60 mm, height=60 mm]{a.jpg}
}
\subfloat[Subscene]{
\includegraphics[width=60 mm, height=60 mm]{b.jpg}
}\\
\caption{original and processed dataset}
\label{fig:fuse_Figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusions}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A sample file for `spieman.cls` uses the deprecated `subfigure` package. You can and should use `subfig`, but with the `caption=false` option.

Here's an example.

I removed all setting about `setspace` and `tocloft`: the copy editors will not be happy at all if you customize the format *they* want.

Don't specify both width and height for images: this would likely distort them.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{spieman}  % 12pt font required by SPIE;

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\title{Sample Paper}

\author[a]{Samadhan}

\begin{document} 

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\keywords{a,b,c}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sect:intro}  % \label{} allows reference to this section

\begin{figure}[!htp]
\centering

\subfloat[Original Multispectral]{%
  \includegraphics[width=60mm]{example-image-a}%
}\quad
\subfloat[Subscene]{%
  \includegraphics[width=60 mm]{example-image-b}
}

\caption{original and processed dataset}
\label{fig:fuse_Figure}
\end{figure}

\section{Conclusions}

\listoffigures
\listoftables

\end{document}
```

[image]